# Unbind and rebind click

Tags: jquery, image, click, bind, unbind

I have the following code:

```
$('#maincontent img').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
    $myFile = $(this).attr('src');
    /*$('#gallery').css('height',0);*/
    $('#gallery').html('<img src="'+$myFile+'" />');
    $('#gallery').fadeIn();
        $('#gallery').click(function(){
            $('#gallery').fadeOut();
                 $('#maincontent img').unbind('click');
                 $('#maincontent img').click(function(){
                      $myFile = $(this).attr('src');
                      $('#gallery').append('<img src="'+$myFile+'" />');
                      $('#gallery img').last().css('display','none').fadeIn();
```

Right now #gallery will fade out whenever I click on it. But the problem is that since there is `.unbind('click')`, I can't click on `$('#maincontent img')` again after `$('#gallery').fadeOut()`. I suppose I'll have to `.bind('click')` again somewhere.

I thought I just had to insert an action in between, for instance:

```
$('#maincontent img').hover(function(){
    $('#maincontent img').bind('click');
```

so that I can click on `#maincontent img` again after I hover on `$('#maincontent img')`. But I'm having trouble getting any response at all. I guess I just don't know what action it needs before it can rebind. Thanks!

`#maincontent` is a div where an external page loads and it contains some image thumbnails. `#gallery` is another div that loads the images from `#maincontent`. Here is the site: http://stampswebdesign.com/manklei/project3/index.html

Comment: what if you don't have that unbind in the first place?

Comment: From the jQuery docs: "As the .click() method is just a shorthand for .on( "click", handler ), detaching is possible using .off( "click" )." Have you tried using off() instead?

Comment: So do I just change .unbind to .off? I tried that but it still isn't working, am I still missing something? Does it mean that when I off it, I'm destroying the event and it just can't be reactivated by simply adding .on again?

Answer (score 0):

It look like you've essentially nested the same block of code within itself. I'd be thinking about breaking that into a function. i.e.

```
var clickEvent = function () {
        $('#gallery').fadeOut();
             $('#maincontent img').unbind('click');
             $('#maincontent img').click(function(){
                  $myFile = $(this).attr('src');
                  $('#gallery').append('<img src="'+$myFile+'" />');
                  $('#gallery img').last().css('display','none').fadeIn();

. . .
```

$('#maincontent img').click(clickEvent);

Then just use the off() function as suggested by ajpocus: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Something like this?

$('#maincontent img').off();

Comment: So do I just change .unbind to .off? I tried that but it still isn't working, am I still missing something? Does it mean that when I off it, I'm destroying the event and it just can't be reactivated by simply adding .on again?

Comment: Try looking at this fiddle I put together. It should make it clearer how you can detach and attach events using on() and off() http://jsfiddle.net/mnvu180o/1/

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still having some issues. I'm trying to define the events after I clicked '#maincontent img' as a function in this way: doThisOnClick = function(){//things happen} $('#something').click(function(){doThisOnClick();}); However I'm still not getting any response, I guess I'm not sure how to define the things that are supposed to happen as a function.

Comment: Hi, the syntax you showed looks OK. Couple of points; first is that on the URL you've given there is no img tag inside #maincontent, so nothing to bind an event to. Also I looked at the site and it throws a Javascript error at line 43 in Chrome. Assuming this is your WIP that may be the source of your problem.